# Cache data using flutter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I am using the forum system in the application. I'm caching categories with no issues, but I'm having problems with posts because when listing posts I am sending "limit" and "category" information to php page.

I am sharing my post codes below.

**I am getting posts with these codes
**

```
List<ForumCategoryModel> fromJson(String jsonString) {
    final data = json.decode(jsonString);
    return List<ForumCategoryModel>.from(data.map((item) => ForumCategoryModel.fromJson(item)));
  }

  Future<List<ForumCategoryModel>> getModel() async {
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "category": widget.category,
      "limit": limit,
    });

    Response response = await dio.get(
      view_url,
      queryParameters: {
        "category": widget.category.toString(),
        "limit": limit.toString(),
      },
      options: buildCacheOptions(const Duration(days: 7), 
          maxStale: const Duration(days: 10),
          forceRefresh: true),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<ForumCategoryModel> list = fromJson(response.data);
      return list;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

**I get information about post owners with these codes
**

```
Future getusr(String uid) async {
    Response response = await dio.get(
      user_info,
      queryParameters: {"user_id": uid.toString()},
      options: buildCacheOptions(Duration(days: 7),
          maxStale: Duration(days: 10),
          forceRefresh: true),
    );

    return json.decode(response.data);
  }
```

**In this section, I list the data I have taken.
**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    getlist();
    super.initState();
  }

  getlist() async {
    cagetoryList = await getModel();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
  }


Expanded(
                        child: AnimationLimiter(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: cagetoryList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              ForumCategoryModel categoryModels = cagetoryList[index];
                              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                                position: index,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                                child: SlideAnimation(
                                  verticalOffset: 50.0,
                                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print(categoryModels.post_id);
                                      },
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 3.0, bottom: 3.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 120.h,
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.1),
                                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                                blurRadius: 2,
                                                offset: const Offset(2.5, 2.5),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                            color: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.1),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 40.h,
                                                  child: FutureBuilder(
                                                    future:
                                                        getusr(categoryModels.user_id.toString()),
                                                    builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
                                                      if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                                                        List list = asyncSnapshot.data;
                                                        print(list[0]["username"].toString());
                                                        return Row(
                                                          children: [
                                                            InkWell(
                                                              onTap: () {
                                                                print(
                                                                    "User id: ${list[0]["user_id"].toString()} ");
                                                              },
                                                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                                                radius: 20.sp,
                                                                backgroundColor:
                                                                    Colors.grey.shade800,
                                                                backgroundImage:
                                                                    CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                                  list[0]["images"].toString(),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            SizedBox(
                                                              width: 15.w,
                                                            ),
                                                            Column(
                                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                  MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                              children: [
                                                                Text(
                                                                  textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                                  "${list[0]["username"].toString()}",
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      fontSize: 15.sp,
                                                                      color: Colors.red,
                                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                                ),
                                                                Text(
                                                                  textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                                  "text",
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      fontSize: 10.sp,
                                                                      color: HexColor("ababab"),
                                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                                                ),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        );
                                                      }
                                                      return const Center(
                                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                              valueColor:
                                                                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                                                      Colors.white)));
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 5.h,
                                                ),
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: RichText(
                                                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    strutStyle: StrutStyle(fontSize: 10.0.sp),
                                                    text: TextSpan(
                                                      text: categoryModels.title,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 15.sp,
                                                          color: HexColor("#B87652"),
                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 5.h,
                                                ),
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: RichText(
                                                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                    maxLines: 1,
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    text: TextSpan(
                                                      text: categoryModels.body,
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                                          fontSize: 13.sp),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 5.h,
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        InkWell(
                                                          onTap: () {},
                                                          child: Icon(
                                                            CupertinoIcons.heart,
                                                            size: 20.sp,
                                                            color: HexColor("#B87652"),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 5.w,
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                          categoryModels.comment_count,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 12.sp,
                                                              color: HexColor("ababab")),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 10.w,
                                                        ),
                                                        InkWell(
                                                          onTap: () {},
                                                          child: Icon(
                                                            CupertinoIcons.bubble_middle_bottom,
                                                            size: 20.sp,
                                                            color: HexColor("#B87652"),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 5.w,
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                          categoryModels.comment_count,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 12.sp,
                                                              color: HexColor("ababab")),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      textScaleFactor: 1,
                                                      categoryModels.creatAt.substring(0, 10),
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 10.sp,
                                                        color: HexColor("ababab"),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

As a result, I am showing posts in a list and user picture and name in posts.

I shoot 10 posts when it first opens.

I want to show them when there is no internet.

Answer (score 1):

I have good and happy news, I found my own answer :)

Below, I am putting the edited version of the code I pulled the data and the additional codes I wrote.

Anyone who needs it can use it :)

```
Future<List<ForumCategoryModel>> getModel() async {
  try {
    Response response = await dio.get(
      view_url,
      queryParameters: {
        "category": widget.category.toString(),
        "limit": limit.toString(),
      },
      options: buildCacheOptions(const Duration(days: 7),
          maxStale: const Duration(days: 10), forceRefresh: true),
    );
    saveList(response.data);
    print("datam : ${response.data}");
    List<ForumCategoryModel> list = fromJson(response.data);
    return list;
  } catch (e) {
    List<ForumCategoryModel> str = await getListem();
    return str;
  }
}


Future getusr(String uid) async {
  try {
    Response response = await dio.get(
      user_info,
      queryParameters: {"user_id": uid.toString()},
      options: buildCacheOptions(const Duration(days: 7),
          maxStale: const Duration(days: 10), forceRefresh: true),
    );
    saveUserCache(uid, response.data);
    print("user data : ${response.data}");
    return json.decode(response.data);
  } catch (e) {
    String data = await getUserCache(uid);
    print(data);
    return json.decode(data);
  }
}
```

These are the codes that I keep and pull the records. The first two codes are for posts - the other two codes are for user information.

```
saveList(String kayit) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString(widget.category, kayit);
}

Future<List<ForumCategoryModel>> getListem() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? liste = prefs.getString(widget.category);

  List<ForumCategoryModel> list = fromJson(liste.toString());
  return list;
}

saveUserCache(String Uid, String data) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString(Uid, data);
}

getUserCache(String Uid) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? liste = prefs.getString(Uid);

  return liste;
}
```

When internet is available, it saves the last 10 posts.

When there is no internet, it shows the last 10 posts.